# Parameter substitution with ${num//[0-9]/}

Tags: bash

Have seen this parameter substitution, but confused abaut what it does exactly.

```
${num//[0-9]/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It removes(*) all digits (0-9) from a string, wherever they occur in the string.  e.g.

```
$ num=abc5x7y999z
$ echo ${num//[0-9]/}
abcxyz
```

(*) actually, it replaces them with the empty string - or whatever string is after the final `/` in that parameter expansion.  From `man bash`:

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just
> as in pathname expansion, Parameter is expanded and the longest match of
> pattern against its value is replaced with string.  The match is performed
> using the rules described under Pattern Matching below.
>
> **If pattern begins with `/`, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.**
> Normally only the first match is replaced.
>
> If pattern begins with `#`,
> it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter.  If
> pattern begins with `%`, it must match at the end of the expanded value of
> parameter.
>
> If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the `/` following
> pattern may be omitted.
>
> If the nocasematch shell option is enabled, the match is performed without
> regard to the case of alphabetic characters.  If parameter is `@` or `*`,
> the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn,
> and the expansion is the resultant list.
>
> If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the
> substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and
> the expansion is the resultant list.

(bolding and extra newlines added by me)

Comment: Wow.  pattern is `[0-9]`, whilst string is the empty string.  Confused the interpretation that  [0-9] was the replacement string.

Comment: yeah, parameter expansion in bash is weird.  looks confusingly similar to sed/perl-like regular expressions, but it's not.